# YouTube is very laggy and slow on Safari but works fine on Chrome

Tags: safari, google-chrome, youtube

This problem started recently, maybe 3 or 4 weeks back. YouTube's interface loads up very slowly on Safari and after the video starts playing, it takes a lot of time for it to forward or rewind.

I had no such problem earlier and YouTube runs smoothly on Google Chrome. I am using a late 2018 MacBook Pro; macOS is updated to Ventura 13.3.1.

Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker (e.g. AdBlock)?

Comment: @Thinkr No ad blockers.

Comment: Is Ambient Mode on? (When you watch a video, click on settings and see if it's enabled)

Comment: This is likely a bug in this version of Safari/Ventura.  See if 13.4, slated for a May release, fixes this.  Please report back with either an [edit] to the original question if it didn’t work, or post an Answer if it does.

Comment: @Allan Sure, will do.

Comment: **Update:** YouTube is _working fine_ now on Safari. MacOS version is 13.3.1 (a) and Safari version is 16.4.

Comment: **New Update:** YouTube is slow again. MacOS version 13.4 and Safari version 16.5 (18615.2.9.11.4)

Comment: **Update:** YouTube works fine when opened in Private Window in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing cache and complete history including cookies solved the lagging problem for me, even though both Ambient Mode and Annotations were toggled ON. Please try this fix.

Comment: This is working (as of now). Thanks!